# An advice required for scalable signal processing architecture with Storm

Tags: mqtt, apache-storm

We are developing an IoT signal processing platform based on STORM, with horizontal scalability in mind. This platform is intended to process several signals simultaneously (gathered from an MQTT topic), by applying to them a chain of signal processing algorithms. So far, our solution includes, as depicted [in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JxHO.png):

- The MQTT Server, with a topic name that includes the identifier of
  the signal (for example, 'patient/1', 'patient/2', …, 'patient/N'.
- An MQTT spout, which is subscribed to all the topics whose names
  match the pattern 'patient/+' (therefore, receiving the value of all 
  the signals and the identifier of each one). We are using this
  approach as we don't know how many signals could be received at some 
  point, and we don't want and different Spout for each possible
  signal!
- Several chained Bolts, one for each signal processing step
  (algorithm).

The preliminary tests of our solutions worked quite well.  By establishing the parallelism hint to the spouts we were able to notice how Storm distributed the load over several machines, improving the throughput of the overall system. However, with this configuration -as far we understand- we have a single point of failure: the MQTT spout, which right now would be a single instance running in one of the Storm's nodes. We know that it won't be a good idea (because we tried it) to enable the parallelism hint to such Spout, as it would have as an effect the creation of multiple MQTT subscribers to the same topic, and therefore the propagation of several copies of the same signal over the processing Bolts.

So, our questions at this point are:

- Do you think our current approach could have any drawback, mostly
  considering our scalability requirements?
- Given the clustering model of Storm, having a single MQTT spout
  (without the parallelism hint) could be considered as a single point of
  failure? (if, for example, the machine it is running in, fails), or
  Storm would guarantee its recovery in other machine of the cluster?
- Given that we are aiming to a scalable architecture we are
  considering 'clusterizable' MQTT servers such as EMQ or ActiveMQ as
  an entry point for the signals. However, we think that our single
  MQTT spout could become a bottleneck at some point. Could you give us
  some advice on how to scale the resources required to read the data
  from the MQTT topics, avoiding the problem of redundant values
  readings?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at something called MQTT shared subscriptions.

This is a new optional feature in the MQTT v5.0 spec (but there are some proprietary implementations in a number of brokers that implement MQTT v3.1 e.g. IBM MessageSight and HiveMQ). This allows multiple subscribers to subscribe to the same topic and have messages be load balanced across them rather than all messages delivered to all subscribers.

I'm not aware of any (production) brokers that implement MQTT v5.0 just yet (April 2018).